# Link Pagination does'nt shown on codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

I have to add pagination to my site and the link does not appear / shown

I Have an controller like this :

```
$data['a'] = 9;
$data['title']  = 'Articles';
$data['content'] = 'home/articles';
$this->load->library('pagination');
$q = $this->db->get_where('articles',array('article_category_id' => 18));
$config['uri_segment'] = 2;
$config['total_rows'] = $q->num_rows();
$config['per_page'] = 3;
$config['base_url'] = base_url() . 'article/';
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$this->db->order_by('id','desc');
$this->db->limit($config['per_page'],$this->uri->segment(2));
$q = $this->db->get_where('articles',array('article_category_id' => 18));
$data['blogs']  = $q;
$data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();
$this->load->view('home/index', $data);
```

and view like this :

```
//Body of the site

Halaman : <?php echo $pagination; ?>
```

[Site View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C8aF3.png)

Comment: This may help https://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/

Comment: thanks dude... i try to change $config['total_rows'] to 50 and the link showed, but when go to the next page, the page is not found ( 404 )

Comment: You may need to set up your routes.php http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html#examples

Comment: here's my route : 

`$route['default_controller']  = "product";


$route['kategori/:num/:any'] = "site/kategori/$1/$2";


$route['faq'] = "site/faq";


$route['scaffolding_trigger'] = "";


$route['consultation'] = "product/consultation";


$route['send_consultation'] = "product/send_consultation";


$route['contact_us'] = "product/contact_us";


$route['mengundang-presentasi'] = "product/undang_kami";


$route['detail/:num/:num/:any'] = "product/detail/$1/$2/$3";


$route['article'] = 'article/article';


$route['article/:num'] = "article/article/$1";`

Comment: You can edit your question buy click on edit button below tags bit to much code to read in comment.

Comment: You should create a model for your database stuff. http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#what-is-a-model